# How do I fix an empty dropdownlist when binding ASP.NET MVC using Dapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to bind a dropdownlist to values in an SQL table using dapper, but the dropdown is empty. Is shows the correct number of rows, but they are all empty. In the debug values from the dapper call I see that it is returning the correct number of rows (3) and that the Id's are correct. - So I think that the data is retrieved correctly but not shown.
I am new to MVC and ASP, so any help is very much appreciated.

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult AddPilot()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Add new pilot.";
        PilotModel program = new PilotModel();
        program.ProgramList = new SelectList(LoadDropDown("SELECT [Id], [Programs] FROM tbl_ProgOverview"), "Id", "Program");            
        return View(program);
    }
```

PilotModel.cs

```
    public class PilotModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WingID { get; set; }
    public string Pilot { get; set; }
    public bool Ship4 { get; set; }
    public bool Ship2 { get; set; }
    public bool Wing { get; set; }
    public bool IP { get; set; }
    public bool ME { get; set; }
    public bool Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
    public string Program2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PrgmStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PrgmEnd { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Prgm2Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Prgm2End { get; set; }
    public bool ExtSync { get; set; }
    public SelectList ProgramList { get; set; }
}
```

}

View.cthtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Program, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">            
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Program, Model.ProgramList, "Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Program, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Helper.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<PilotModel> LoadDropDown(string sql)
    {
        return SqlDataAccess.GetDropDown<PilotModel>(sql);
    }
```

DataAccess.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<PilotModel> GetDropDown<PilotModel>(string sql)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return cnn.Query<PilotModel>(sql);
        }
    }
```

The table "tbl_ProgOverview" has only 2 columns ("Id", "Programs"), and all I am trying to achieve is to have the dropdown in model.Program, show a list of the values in the "Programs" column of this table.
Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally, I would say "avoid screenshots", but in this case: the screenshot genuinely helped me identify the problem, i.e. I can see that the `Program` member is `null`. So: :thumbsup:

Comment: Knew the problem was there, just didn’t know why;-) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper: cares about names.

You have the SQL:

```cs
SELECT [Id], [Programs] FROM tbl_ProgOverview
```

but your c# property is `Program` (or at least, I presume that's what you intend to map it to). Dapper is going to ignore the `Programs` column and not set `Program`, hence why it is `null` in the screen-shot.

Try:

```cs
SELECT [Id], [Programs] as Program FROM tbl_ProgOverview
```

This re-maps the projected column name in the SQL to `Program`, to match what Dapper is looking for. Alternatively, you could renaming the C# property to `Programs`.

As a side note: when you use literals like `"Id"` or `"Program"` in your C# code, it makes it hard to rename those properties later if you need to. You might want to try `nameof(PilotModel.Id)` / `nameof(PilotModel.Program)`, which avoids hard-coding those literals. If you rename them: it will fix your binding code automatically (or at least tell you that no such member exists).